# How to copy html content with original formatting to vim editor

Tags: vim, formatting

Trying to `copy/paste` html from this [source - second live demo example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

[image]

When I copy the `code`, output is wrong formatted and it looks like the following in vim editor:

What is the best way to copy this code from web with original formatting ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When pasting code like this, you want to tell Vim not to auto-indent the code, and keep the original indentation.

To achieve it, simply run this command in Vim, to start pasting mode :

```
:set paste
```

When finished, to re-activate auto indentation :

```
:set nopaste
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Get yourself a Vim built with clipboard support (the official download from vim.org on Windows, `vim-gtk` or some similar package on Linux, MacVim on Mac OS X).
2. Use `"+p` or `"*p`.